# Cant find UITextField after by view tag after moving app to background

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have code which initialize UITextField with porperty SecureTextEntry to prevent user screenshot when the app start

```
var field = new UITextField();
field.SecureTextEntry = true;
field.Tag = _fieldViewTag;
var mainView = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
mainView.AddSubview(field);
field.CenterYAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(mainView.CenterYAnchor).Active = true;
field.CenterXAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(mainView.CenterXAnchor).Active = true;
mainView.Layer.SuperLayer?.AddSublayer(field.Layer);
field.Layer.Sublayers?.First()?.AddSublayer(mainView.Layer);
```

User can turn on/off this option

```
public void AllowScreenShot()
{
            UIView fieldView = null;
            
            foreach (var view in UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.Subviews)
            {
                fieldView = view.ViewWithTag(_fieldViewTag);

                if (fieldView != null)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (fieldView != null)
            {
                ((UITextField)fieldView).SecureTextEntry = false;
            }
}

public void DisallowScreenShot()
{
            UIView fieldView = null;
                
            foreach (var view in UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.Subviews)
            {
                fieldView = view.ViewWithTag(_fieldViewTag);

                if (fieldView != null)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (fieldView != null)
            {
                ((UITextField)fieldView).SecureTextEntry = true;
            }
}
```

but after moving app to the background and than back to foreground I can not find UITextField by tag
UITextField disappears in KeyWindow.Subviews

Comment: If it is not there, maybe add it again? Could remember its `SecureTextEntry` value in `DidEnterBackground`, then look for it in `WillEnterForeground`. If not found, create it again, with the remembered state.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve it is not a solution for me, because if user turns on screenshot protection (SecureTextEntry to true) then moves to the background, and then to the foreground, and then turns off this option user still can not do screenshots it somehow remembered it and I can not find this field to set SecureTextEntry to false

Comment: So I did not find the right solution, so I just ask user to restart app after changing option